# Get information from a selected CellList item

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to extract a modelID from a cellList. But i cant find any methods for doing so. At the moment i put data into a list (here is the ModelID) and then send this list to the cellList. I suppose it works in the current state cause the window alert box shows all the items i put into the list. But i would like to extract the ModelID from the chosen item in the CellList. Is this possible? and if yes, how can it be achieved?

```
List<String> newData = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (ModelInfo modelInfo : getModelInfoList())
            {
                int modelID = modelInfo.getModelID();
                int modelCreator = modelInfo.getModelCreator();
                String modelName = modelInfo.getModelName();
                String modelCreationDate = modelInfo.getModelCreationDate();
                newData.add("ModelID:" + modelID + "Creator: " + modelCreator + " Diagram name: " + modelName + " Diagram creation date " + modelCreationDate);
            }
```

And a selection handler

```
 // Add a selection model to handle user selection.
    final SingleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<String>();
    cellList.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
      public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        String selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        if (selected != null) {
          //Extract MODELID TODO
          Window.alert("You selected: " + selected);
        }
      }
    });
```

Best regards,
Kerrai

Comment: Your goal is to access the String selected outside of the onSelectionChange handler?

Comment: Well not per say, my goal is to access the ModelID that will be the first number in the string.

I hoped that it could be done in a good manner, i could always end the first part with a sign such as "/" and parse the string until such sign is found and extract the modelID that way..

Comment: You should pass a list of the `ModelInfo` objects to the `CellList` instead of a `String`. The you can use modelInfo.getId() or something like that. You'll need a custom cell to do that though: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html